# How to import functions from a library with Webpack Encore from Symfony?

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack

I want to import `bootbox` from `bootbox.min.js` but I got this error :

> TypeError: setting getter-only property "bootbox"

and it works without Webpack Encore from Symfony.

Here is my news.js file where I call `bootbox` :

```
var bootbox = require('./bootbox.min');
(...)
a2.onclick = function (event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
        if (result) {
            window.location.href = "/" + locale + '/news/delete/' + news.id;
        }
    });
}
(...)
```

I also export `bootbox` in `bootbox.min.js` :

```
(...)
export {bootbox};
```

How to make bootbox accessible from my news.js file with Webpack Encore from Symfony ?

Comment: Looks like you are exporting it as an object property, try calling it by `bootbox.bootbox.confirm(...)` or use `module.exports = bootbox`/`export default bootbox`

Comment: Actually I removed `export {bootbox}` from `bootbox.min.js` and it works.